# passing full name from batch file to vbs file and then run a word macro with it

Tags: vba, batch-file, vbscript

I have a batch file that fetches the full name characteristic of an ad user and sets it as variable n. I need to take that variable and pass it into a vbs file and then run a word macro from that vbscript. Here's what I have:

Batch:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('NET USER "username" /DOMAIN ^| FIND /I "Full name"') do set n=%%i
cscript //NoLogo H:\firstRotation\mgmtSSnD\CMMR\fullName.vbs %1
```

vbs:

```
fullName = WScript.Arguments(0)
Set objWord = GetObject(,"Word.Application")
Set x = objWord.Documents.Open("mypath\my.docm")
objWord.Run "test", fullName
```

vba:

```
Private sub test(ByVal x As String)
Msgbox (x)
End sub
```

As of right now, I keep getting a VBScript "subscript out of range error" so my problem has to do with passing the variable from batch to vbs.

Comment: The `for` result is presumably `%%i` rather then `%1` (which is an argument passed into the batch file)

Comment: When I do that I get a "wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment" error

Comment: The closing parentheses in front of do is missing, tranfer fault or typo? Full Name is likely to contain  spaes, so has to be quoted.

Comment: Im assuming you're wanting to pass the returned output from your `For` loop to the VBScript, i.e. `CScript //B //NoLogo "H:\firstRotation\mgmtSSnD\CMMR\fullName.vbs" "%n%"`

Comment: You mean `x.Run` rather than `objWord.Run`, right? And I think there is a `,` too much in the `GetObject` line...

Comment: @compo yes and I want to use both the 3rd and 4th tokens of the string as a part of the variable. Any idea how to change the "tokens=*" argument to do that?

Comment: @Nicolas, use `"Tokens=2*" %%A In (` then `Set "n=%%B"`. Alternatively if there are more than `4` tokens use `"Tokens=3-4" %%A In (` then `Set "n=%%A %%B"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `n` would contain `Full Name _spaces_ User Name` but you don't use it to pass it to the vbs.

This batch ignores `Full Name` and passes the result in `%%B` directly to the vbscript.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2*" %%A in (
    'NET USER "username" /DOMAIN ^| FIND /I "Full name"'
) do cscript //NoLogo H:\firstRotation\mgmtSSnD\CMMR\fullName.vbs "%%B"
```

The quotes passed from the batch get stripped in the vbs, you have to requote.
I assume the error message comes from the vba.

```
fullName = WScript.Arguments(0)
Set objWord = GetObject(,"Word.Application")
Set x = objWord.Documents.Open("mypath\my.docm")
objWord.Run "test", """fullName"""
```

Parsing `net user` output with default delimiter space (successive count as 1):

```
        "Full Name                    Anthoni B. Caesar"
Tokens     1   2                        3     4    5
Delims       _    ____________________       _  _
For-Var  %%A  %%B                      %%C    %%D %%E
```

Comment: I get an invalid property assignment error when I do this

Comment: See changed / extended answer.

Comment: nevermind my first comment, your first solution would've worked I just missed the //B argument in running the cscript. Thank you for your help!

Comment: The `*` takes the rest after token 2 in the variable %%B.  To have separate meta variables you could use `tokens=1-5` (in case a middle initial is passed) and pass them indivdually as %%C,%%D,%%E see appended scheme in the answer.